# When attempting to remove single quotes from text file, they are replaced with <98>

Tags: bash, text, terminal

I am trying to remove all punctuation from a text file, and am nearly successful with this code:

```
$ cat file.txt | tr -s '[:punct:]' ' ' | tr -s ' *' ' '
```

However, this code leaves all of the single and double quotes still in the file. Those quotes are actually this character : `’`. That is not a single quote, which look like: `'`.  After realizing this, I ran this line of code on the already altered text:

```
tr -d '’'
```

This resulted in my text file replacing each single quote with <98>.  Why is this happening? I'd appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sed 's/[\xe2\x80\x99[:punct:]]//g' file
```

Example:

```
echo 'Abc.!?#,"`’'"'" | sed 's/[\xe2\x80\x99[:punct:]]//g'
```

Output:

```
Abc
```

Comment: This somewhat obscurely assumes that the file is encoded in UTF-8. While that is not an unreasonable assumption, there are many ways it could go wrong. Perhaps then [edit] the question with more information about the file's encoding, your locale settings, etc. The [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/oharacter-encoding/info) has some additional hints for troublehooting.

Comment: I assume UTF-8. With your change to the question, you have changed the decisive sign.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I only intended to add quotes for disambiguation. I don't see anything other than that in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48138839/revisions), either. Can you please point to the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault! Because of the different fonts it looked like two different characters.